# NameError name 'F' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

when i tried this code to add 10 point to user after he fill out one survey it show this error

However, I am running into a problem. I get the error:

```
models.py", line 22, in give_coins
user.coins = F('coins') + count
NameError: name 'F' is not defined
```

models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/',default="",null=True, blank=True)
    coins = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    def get_image(self):
        if self.user_pic and hasattr(self.user_pic, 'url'):
            return self.user_pic.url
        else:
            return '/path/to/default/image'
    def give_coins(user, count):
        user.coins = F('coins') + count
        user.save(update_fields=('coins',))
        user.refresh_from_db(fields=('coins',))
```

views.py :

```
@require_http_methods(["POST"])
def submit_survey(request):
    request.user.give_coins(count=10)
    form_data = request.POST.copy()
    form_items = list(form_data.items())
    print("form_items", form_items)
    form_items.pop(0)  # the first element is the csrf token. Therefore omit it.
    survey = None
    for item in form_items:
        # Here in 'choice/3', '3' is '<choice_id>'.
        choice_str, choice_id = item
        choice_id = int(choice_id.split('/')[1])
        choice = Choice.objects.get(id=choice_id)
        if survey is None:
            survey = choice.question.survey
        choice.votes = choice.votes + 1
        choice.save()
    if survey is not None:
        participant = Participant(survey=survey, participation_datetime=timezone.now())
        participant.save()
    return redirect('/submit_success/')
```

so .. where is the error here

Comment: The error is coming from your user model  since you haven't define any attribute with the  F hence Django would throw an error  in this part of your code *def give_coins(user, count):
        user.coins = F('coins') + count

Comment: ok i understand you now , so What do you suggest I do to fix the problems?

Comment: You need to import the class before using it... `from django.db.models import F`

Comment: Yeah you where suppose to import  F then it should work

Comment: ohh thanks really man , i'am new to django and i'am now learn more about django ,, you helped me a lot to understand models in django

Comment: other question ,, if i want to pass data from model to html to display it for user what i must do

Comment: i tried ,,,,   {{user.give_coins}}    ,,, but it not show on screen

Comment: i fix it by do this ,,, {{user.coins}}  thanks man again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import **"F"** in **"models.py"** as shown below:

```
from django.db.models import F
```